# Plugin gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init> error

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying out a konfetti plugin in my Android application (https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti)
I have copied and pasted the code from the example in to my code, but the `streamFor` call here

```
        viewKonfetti.build()
                .addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA)
                .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
                .setSpeed(1f, 5f)
                .setFadeOutEnabled(true)
                .setTimeToLive(2000L)
                .addShapes(Shape.Square, Shape.Circle)
                .addSizes(Size(12))
                .setPosition(-50f, viewKonfetti.width + 50f, -50f, -50f)
                .streamFor(300, 5000L)
```

gives me the following error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V in class Lkotlin/jvm/internal/FunctionReferenceImpl; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl' appears in /data/app/com.example.iogame-Kf5I23Yoh14KRwdJEJD5EQ==/base.apk)
    at nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.emitters.RenderSystem$1.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
    at nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.emitters.RenderSystem.<init>(RenderSystem.kt:40)
    at nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.emitters.RenderSystem.<init>(RenderSystem.kt:27)
    at nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.ParticleSystem.startRenderSystem(ParticleSystem.kt:286)
    at nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.ParticleSystem.streamFor(ParticleSystem.kt:245)
    at com.example.iogame.MainActivity$setAnswerOnClickListener$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:77)
```

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By the way, there's [this](https://github.com/DopeDevX/CongratsShower) library for confetti. It's simple lightweight and highly customizable.

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary Thanks, I`ll take  a look at it and compare the results based on performance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a closed issue on this problem.
Changing to a newer Kotlin version (1.4.10) fixed the problem (https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti/issues/193):

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}